# Send parameter with accentuation c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an page and in my Send event, I need pass as a parameter an value "Name".
But this name have accentuation and, in example for name "Raúl Lozada" sends "`Ra&#250;l Lozada`" to my procedure parameter.
How I can correct it?
In my HTML page, it loads correctly!

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="User" HeaderText="User" />    

SqlParameter myParam4 = oCommand.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NChar);
            myParam4.Value = row.Cells[0].Text;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to HTML unescape the string, before sending to the DB:

Use [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx):

```
myParam4.Value = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[0].Text);
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant my friend. You're another person I always learn something from when reading your answers!